# Struts2 Access specific index of list when index is a variable

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I'm having some trouble accessing a specific element of a list when the index is a variable.

When the index is just a number, I have no issues at all displaying what I'm looking for.

```
<s:property value="#session.userList[1].email" />
```

That works perfectly, and displays the email found in that element of UserList

However, when I change the index to be a variable, I'm having difficulties finding the proper way to write the ognl statement. I've tried every combination of %# I can think of with no luck.

```
<s:set var="userIndex" >${param.index}</s:set>
<s:property value="#session.userList[#userIndex].email" />
```

How exactly should I format my ognl statement?

Comment: It's a string like that. Use the `value` attribute as Roman says. Stuff like this is trivial to debug because you can look at the type of the value you've set.

Comment: @DaveNewton Right, the value keep the type, but parameters are converted to string and back to the value if I am correct.

Comment: Params are strings, but even if they weren't, when a value Is the *body* of a param tag, it'll always be a string. When it's evaluated as a value *attribute* Then it's evaled as whatever the ognl expression is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should format it like in this example:

```
<s:set var="userIndex" value="%{@java.lang.Integer@valueOf(#parameters.index)}" />
<s:property value="%{#session.userList[#userIndex].email}" />
```

If you are working with the struts tags better use OGNL for evaluate expressions instead of EL. Force OGNL to evaluate whole expression not a part.

Needed to convert to integer type the value of the variable. String types used for names.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN ALSO USE

```
<s:set var="index" value="%{@java.lang.Integer@valueOf(#row.index)}" />
```

this is set a integer value for index

then you can access specific value of a list

```
<s:property value="%{yourListObject.get(#index).yourField}" />
```